# I want to solve an Entropy Maximization question with CVXPY

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, entropy, cvxpy

I'm using python but there is a problem with s.t. part and 2 last lines,
I don't know what I did wrong, and I couldn't find any similar examples,
I would appreciate any help   . 
[image]

```
import numpy as np
c = np.array([[3,11,18,22],
              [12,3,12,19],
              [15.5,13,5,7],
              [24,18,8,5]])
C=1200
O=[400,460,400,702]
D=[260,400,500,802]
L=4
K=4


import cvxpy as cp
x = cp.Variable((K, L), PSD=True)
obj = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(cp.entr(x)))
#error
constraints = [(for j=1 to L: cp.sum(x[:j])==O[j]), (for i =1 to L: cp.sum(x[:j])==D[i]), (cp.sum(cp.sum(c @x)) == C)]
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
opt_val = prob.solve(solver=cp.CVXOPT, verbose=True)

print("\nThe optimal value is:", prob.value)
print('\nThe optimal solution is:')
print(x.value)
```

Comment: You cannot use Julia syntax when programming in Python. They are two different programming languages.

Comment: but isn't cvxpy for python?

Comment: Yes, but the code you copied was Julia code and not Python code. Copy-paste is evil, but you take it to new heights.

Comment: but it was written in a cvxpy sample

Comment: Please show the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-write your code:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
c = np.array([[3,11,18,22],
              [12,3,12,19],
              [15.5,13,5,7],
              [24,18,8,5]])
C=1200
O=[400,460,400,702]
D=[260,400,500,802]
L=4
K=4



x = cp.Variable((K, L),pos=True)  #pos AS X is allowed to be zero in your last constraint
obj = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(cp.entr(x)))
#error
constraints=[]
for i in range (K): 
    constraints += [cp.sum(x,axis=0)==O[i]] #Assign all the sum of columns to be equal O
for j in range (L):              
    constraints += [cp.sum(x,axis=1)==D[j]]   #Assign all the sum of rows to be equal D
constraints+=   [ (cp.sum(cp.multiply(c,x)) == C)]   # The sum of dot product of the c,x matrix equal to C

prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)

prob.solve()
print("\nThe optimal value is:", prob.value)
print('\nThe optimal solution is:')
print(x.value)
```

Unfortunately, it returns:
The optimal value is: -inf
The optimal solution is:
None

I am not sure of the constants in your example should converg to a solution. Anyway I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: thanks for you effort, I'll changed the coded again to see if it works with other solvers or not and I got an error that "cvxpy.error.SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['CVXOPT']) do not support the cones output by the problem (ExpCone, PSD), or there are not enough constraints in the problem."
while it's been said this solver supports the problem

Comment: @Aisa.Imn The "PSD=True" in your code is probably not necessary. I don't think you really want a semidefninte matrix variable. Probably "pos=true" is what you mean.